# Gaussian Process gives negative prediction mean

Tags: gaussian-process

I have used Gaussian Process for regression task and it gives me negative values for the prediction mean in some of the observations, although the dependent variable is always above 0.
The data is standardized and is considered zero mean function for the mean. How is that possible to happen? Just to mention that after I make the predictions, I multiply by the variance and add the mean so I can get the non standardized values for the predictions.

Comment: Hello New Contributor, welcome on CrossValidated. Have you considered adding data and code to make details more explicit? Consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Set "normalize_y = True" in GaussianProcessRegressor argument